# Change DIV class on click action Ember

Tags: ember.js

I want to change the DIV class base on CLICK action. I am trying to make a floating sidebar like this http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar.html

This demo has only three lines of code for toggle-ing the class.

```
<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
    </script>
```

I want to achive same thing but in ember way. Below is my HTML code:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="pull-left" id="main_menu">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">{{#link-to "selectImage"}}<h4>Choose Picture</h4>{{/link-to}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">{{#link-to "message"}}<h4>Write Message</h4>{{/link-to}}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><h4>Account info</h4></a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><h4>Recent Orders</h4></a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><h4>How to</a></h4></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><h4>FAQ</a></h4></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Begin page content -->
        <div class="container" id="page_content">
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
    <!-- End page content -->
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="cards/index">
        <h1>
        <button class="pull-left btn btn-default" data-target="#main_menu" {{action 'changeClass'}}>
           <img src="images/icons/menu_tablet.png" class="main_menu"/>
        </button>
</script>
```

Now I do not know how can I use the action to change the class in WRAP div. I will really appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the action handler within the controller for cards/index

```
Controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    changeClass: function() {
     // Run logic here
    }
   }
})
```